# JSJ-type decompositions for knots

Tags: knot-theory, 3-manifolds

According to Wikipedia, JSJ decomposition for 3-manifolds is the following statement:

"Irreducible orientable closed (i.e., compact and without boundary) 3-manifolds have a unique (up to isotopy) minimal collection of disjointly embedded incompressible tori such that each component of the 3-manifold obtained by cutting along the tori is either atoroidal or Seifert-fibered."

Knots in $S^3$ have a unique prime decomposition (with respect to connected sum): "the pieces along cutting the complement of the knot along essential annuli are unique." Is there an analogous result to JSJ-decomposition for knot complements cut along essential 4-punctured spheres?

Comment: This is the content of Bonahon and Siebenmann's manuscript.  It's closely related to the JSJ-decomposition of the 2-sheeted branched cover of the (sphere, knot) pair.  See the "New Geometric Splittings..." link. https://dornsife.usc.edu/francis-bonahon/preprints/

Comment: Thank you @RyanBudney